# Evaluating parameters in SSRS report heading

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, query-string

Hi I am trying to create a report in SSRS for a survey. The report title should have the survey date displayed. Below is what my report looks like in excel:

[image]

It has the survey date in report heading. I am trying to do similar thing in SSRS but not able to display the dates. This is what my report looks like in SSRS:

[image]

Sorry I had to blacken some of the fields. Anyways so in SSRS I created two parameters @reportStartDate and @reportNextDate. I want these parameters to be populated with yesterday's date and current date. So the param @reportStartDate should be yesterday's date and @reportNextDate should be today's date.

I tried multiple things and haven't figured out the solution yet. In the dataset properties, I assigned the following expression to the parameters:

```
@reportStartDate = DATEADD (DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
@reportNextDate =  DATEADD (DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Here is how I created the parameters:

[image]

And here is how I assigned the parameters with expression in Dataset properties:

[image]

But after this when I preview the report, I get the error

[image]

I am working on SSRS for first time and have been struggling with this issue from almost more than a day. Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you have accepted an answer but unless I'm mistaken it looks like a simple case of your title expression being wrong.

Your title expression should be something like

```
="Hotel Mobile Debrief Detail Report from " & Parameters!reportStartDate.Value & " to " & Parameters!reportNextDate.Value
```

There is no need to add datasets simply to display the parameter values in a text box.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I was able to do this without creating datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new dataset that contains the following

```
select DATEADD (DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), -1) as startdate,
       DATEADD (DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) as enddate
```

You should then be able to access these fields as internal in the parameter select screen
Report data will look like this:

[image: Report date]

Make the parameter visibility to internal as you don't want the user to see it.
[image: Parameters1]

Get values from the new dataset and repeat the process for end date
[image: Parameters2]